# Why should we be aware of licenses?

Tags: licensing

I know this is common question, but why should a programmer be aware of software licenses as well as extensions and plugins licenses?

I'm working in a company which focuses on the business process (Ruby on Rails) and I'm curious as to why they are strict on such licenses in the project development.

What licenses should I be aware of and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Licenses are conditional terms of use.

If you breach the terms of a license, you can be sued.  Depending upon the licenses and the legal jurisdictions involved, there can be severe penalties for not abiding by the terms of the license.  Those penalties could bankrupt a company, or could cause the company to lose their claim to their software.

Some licenses heavily restrict what you can do with code, such as the copyleft provision within GPL's source code release requirements.  Other licenses restrict usage to only academic or noncommercial use.  And other licenses have free personal versions but require paid commercial versions.

If you are in the business of writing software, then you have to carefully pick what outside software you integrate with as their licenses may impact your ability to sell your software or affect how you structure your business model.

Your product managers are being strict because they are trying to minimize risk and avoid complications created by using conflicting licenses or licenses that may harm their business goals.

Answer (score 4):

Professional courtesy comes to mind. If you want other's to follow your licensing (+ fee's), then you should respect and uphold licensing within the industry.

Risk mitigation is also important to lawyers, who often try and protect businesses against bad risks. EULA and licensing of 3rd party code is all about risk management for both parties, supplier and consumer.

Comment: I also came here to say, "because it's the right thing to do."

Answer (score 1):

Since licenses are not identical to contracts, because licenses are set by authors of a product not by a copyright holders originally, but a developer/author can allow or transfer rights to set a required license to third person, to so called copyright holder. This rule of course can or could be specified by a contract between a developer and a hiring company/other developer. By default right to set license is kept to the product's author or a group of authors.

In case when an author, in thine case author of an application, transfer by a contract rights to set a license on a product, he lost that right, by keep the right by be specified as an author in the product's description. It is so called [inalienable right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alienation_%28property_law%29). Unlike the right to specify a license for your product that is an [alienable right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alienation_%28property_law%29).

So, you shell be away of not only a license, like variaous type of [EULAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) (that are really contracts), and open licenses like [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/choose/), or [MIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) licenses, which are mostly used in Rails/Gem applications, but when you are working on a contract, of the cotract, and its containment accoding the alienable rights.

Answer (score 1):

There are already great answers here, but I want to throw in my 2¢.

1. By using the piece of software, you've agreed to the license. Know what you are agreeing to is a general piece of advice which applies to all of life.
2. By using the piece of software, the legal entity you are working for is bound to the terms of the license. If this is your employer, you may be exposing them to millions of dollars in legal fees and/or personally committing a [career limiting move](http://www.eps.mcgill.ca/jargon/jargon.html#CLM).
3. By using the piece of software, you are showing that you value that software. Show respect for things you value. In software, that respect is conforming to the terms of the license. As a corollary, if you don't value a piece of software, then don't use it.

Comment: That you agree to the license by merely using the software isn't that clear. Typically users have to agree to a EULA whose legal standing is tricky. It's only clear that you can't legally distribute software without obtaining a license.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That is an interesting legal opinion which could cost millions of dollars to prove. I'm not willing to have any entity I work for inadvertently test that opinion.

Answer (score 1):

As answer by means of example, consider a simple (rather common) sort of problem:

You have a problem that requires you lookup the distance in miles between two given US postal zip-codes for a search feature. It turns out there is a library available that does this super easily, so you just grab it and - problem solved! You just cut days, or weeks, out of the project schedule.

Uh...but, is that legal? Well, that's where licenses and copyright come in. Sometimes code/software is provided "free for non-commercial use", for instance, but with the requirement that everyone else has to contact the author to negotiate a contract or pay a license fee. Some licenses, especially in the GPL realm, permits any use of the code, so long as it is not compiled together with other code and sold without attribution or under a different license.

This quickly turns into something that makes you want to cry, or at least makes you willing to turn your monitor upside down and from then on do all your coding while suspended from the ceiling by your toes. It's just a filthy mess.

If software is your business and you are in charge of this, you'll need to do a lot of learning about what licenses conflict with others, pros and cons, etc. But if you are working for someone else who is kind enough to have paid out thousands in lawyer fees to develop a policy of what code/software licenses can and cannot be used in the project - stop what you are doing and go give those people a hug. They probably need it. They might sue you for it though...so maybe just say "thank you" instead.

To answer your question about specific licenses, you don't necessarily have to be aware of any particular license, just whatever the business says is and is not OK. There are so very many licenses, with so many individual incarnations and details, and in a business setting there are very different demands than in a personal project.

The final "why" is three-fold: being a good "software community" citizen by not ripping off people's work and accidentally (or intentionally) passing it off as your own or otherwise stepping one people's toes who are literally giving you hours of work for "free", not exposing the company to potentially millions of dollars in legal costs, and making sure people are getting paid for use of their work if this is appropriate.

I wish it was all unnecessary, back in the old days of the "free information" hacker dream...but in part that dream is why so many software licenses became necessary. It's an interesting history, far beyond the scope of this Q&A. But they exist, so you can either do lots of research...or take your companies word it. Their policies do exist for really, really good reasons (or at least in this particular case).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of the question (very roughly), for commercial projects you should probably be aware of:

- BSD or Apache style licenses - basically: do what you want
- GPL - basically: avoid unless you are ok with having your own code under GPL
- LGPL - can use as a library freely as long as you don't change it, other uses gets you back to GPL
- Others - look at them individually

Now, this is very rough and IANAL and everything. I recommend you look at [opensource.org](http://opensource.org/licenses)  for more details.

(Also: why does it matter? Imagine the Ruby on Rails license says 'you have to pay us 50% of your revenue to use it' or 'we own all the code you wrote based on that platform')